# Python - Deleting names from a list inside a different document

Tags: python

I found a better way doing this.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import random
# Import a file with the names in class
name = [i.strip().split() for i in open("input.txt").readlines()]
# Draw a name
a =(random.choice(name))
# Print the name
print a
# Find the index from the list
x = name.index(a)
# Delete the name from the list 
list.remove(x)
```

The input.txt is:

```
Andrew
Andrea
....
```

Still what's the error here?

When running I get this error:
['Andrew']

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hey\Desktop\Program\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    list.remove(x)
TypeError: descriptor 'remove' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: `name.remove(x)` takes the element to be removed, not it's index, so either use `name.remove(a)` or `name.pop(x)`. See [some documentation on lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: list.remove(x) should be name.remove(x)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You don't need index. remove takes an element and not an index.
2. Replace list with name.

Code:

```
import random
name = [i.strip().split() for i in open("input.txt").readlines()]
a =(random.choice(name))
print a
name.remove(a)
```

To delete it in the file:

```
import random
name = open("input.txt", 'r').readlines()
name.remove(random.choice(name))
with open("input.txt", 'w') as f:
    for row in name:
        f.write(row)
```

Note My input.txt could be else than yours. Mine is seperated by endlines. This algorithm works for:

```
Andrew
Andrea
....
```

Comment: Thank you! Still I am looking for the name to be deleted from the file permament, so "Andrew" wouldnt be on the list next time

Comment: Thank you again! Still in the "to delete it in the file".  I need to print the random.choice. And the printed and deleted name need to be the same